# Constructing central series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Problem Statement: Prove nilpotent group is supersolvable. [A finite nilpotent group has supersolvable series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067832/a-finite-nilpotent-group-has-supersolvable-series)

The link above uses $p$-group and direct product. But suppose we do not do that, the definition of niloptent seems to be only there EXISTS a central series. But can we claim that we can CONSTRUCT one as long as we follow $G/G_i \leq Z(G/G_{i-1})$?

Comment: The problem statement is false is general, but it is true for finitely generated nilpotent groups.

Comment: Also, for the proof of the result for finite groups (as specified in Brauer Suzuki's answer), you do not need to construct a central series (whatever that means), the existence of a central series is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your groups are finite. Let $1=G_0\le\ldots\le G_n=G$ be a central series. Since $G_i/G_{i-1}\le Z(G/G_{i-1})$, all subgroups of $G_i/G_{i-1}$ are normal in $G/G_{i-1}$. By the correspondence theorem, all subgroups of $G_i$ containing $G_{i-1}$ are normal in $G$. Since $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is abelian, we can refine our central series until $|G_i/G_{i-1}|$ is a prime for $i=1,\ldots,n$. But this means that $G$ is supersolvale.

Comment: You said "Since $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is abelian, we can refine...". But why does "abelian" guarantee that during refinement, $Z(G/...)$ is non-trivial?

Comment: Note that $G_i/G_{i-1}\le Z(G/G_{i-1})$ is equivalent to $[G,G_i]\subseteq G_{i-1}$ (where $[,]$ denotes the commutator). Now lets add $H$ with $G_{i-1}<H<G_i$. Then clearly $H/G_{i-1}\le G_i/G_{i-1}\le Z(G/G_{i-1})$ and $[G,G_i]\le G_{i-1}\le H$, so $G_i/H\le Z(G/H)$.

Comment: Actually, we do not keep track of the central property. It's enough to construct a normal series with quotients of prime order.

Comment: Sure we do not keep track by your commutator proof above. Don't we still need to ensure that the element we use to generate $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is coming from $Z(G/G_i)$, i.e. it cannot just be a random prime cyclic quotient?

Comment: Let me rephrase: $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is abelian, so it has a normal series with quotients of prime order. Now we lift this series to a normal series of $G$.